# Reading from HDFS into Spark

Tags: mysql, hadoop, apache-spark, sqoop

I am attempting to read a file from HDFS into Spark and perform some data processing on it. Originally, I used Sqoop to transfer the file from a MySQL database into Spark. The SQL database table has three columns - movieid, title, and genres. I was wondering how I should format sc.textFile to properly pull the file.

Running hdfs dfs -ls, I see:

```
drwxr-xr-x  - hduser1 supergroup           0 2017-03-20 23:51 movies
```

Running hdfs dfs -ls movies, I see:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser1 supergroup           0 2017-03-20 23:51 movies/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--  1 hduser1 supergroup     1290474 2017-03-20 23:51 movies/part-m-0000
```

What I am trying to figure out is what would go in the below function:

```
case class Movie(movieid: String, title: String, genres: String)
val movieRdd: RDD[Movie] = sc.textFile(***WHAT GOES HERE***).map(-formatting-)
```

Comment: try this: `sc.textFile("/movies")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can code in the below format:

```
sc.textFile(hdfs://NamenodeIPAddress:Port/DirectoryLocation)

example: sc.textFile(hdfs://127.0.0.1:8020/user/movies)
```

Please change the IP Address as per your Name Node IP address and path as per your location.

**Hope this Helps!!!...**

Comment: Appreciate the response! Ended up having to use port 54310 on localhost but it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Does Sqoop drop the SQL schema when you copy files into HDFS? Or is there a way to recover it?